# Vmmem process high memory usage makes Win10 very slow

Tags: memory, performance, docker, wsl2

I run WSL2 on my Win10 machine with 32GB RAM. I use it for Docker and WSL. Since some days back the computer extremely slow, it freezes every 10-15 seconds.

```
λ wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
```

I've capped the WSL2 memory at 3GB, contents of `.wslconfig` below:

```
[wsl2]
memory=3GB   # Limits VM memory in WSL 2 up to 3GB
processors=4 # Makes the WSL 2 VM use two virtual processors
```

This is described [here](https://www.koskila.net/how-to-solve-vmmem-consuming-ungodly-amounts-of-ram-when-running-docker-on-wsl/) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4166).

The memory seems to be capped looking at the process...

[image: Task manager]

---

But the physical memory usage is still massive. What I can sum up in the first screenshot doesn't even get close to below.

[image: Memory usage]

---

Any advice is welcome!